# Automate an application using scripting, managing multiple terminals

Tags: bash

I am new to Ubuntu and Bash scripting. I am working on a project to give a demo on an SDN application to my class. I need some help in scripting to create the demo. Please help in case if you have any idea on what am asking.

The demo uses a tool called mininet. I need just one script so that I can automate the whole of my demo.

The commands I need to run are given in order below.

1. Run "`sudo mn`" on the terminal. This changes the prompt from

   ```
   /mininet$ sudo mn
   ```

   to

   ```
   mininet>
   ```
2. Now on this terminal where the prompt is `mininet>`, I need to run `xterm h1` followed by `xterm h2` to create separate terminals for two hosts created by mininet.
3. I have to access the xterm terminal for h1 and run a command there . eg: `ifconfig`
4. I have to access the xterm terminal for h2 and run a command there . eg : `set ip address`
5. I have to run a ping in xterm terminal for h1 and while this is happening, i want to access terminals of h2 and start a ping in xterm terminals of h2.
6. I have to go back to the previous terminal from where the xterm terminals were spawned. `mininet>` prompt one. and run `exit` and then when the prompt goes back to normal `/mininet$` i have to `sudo mn -c`.

All of this should be done from one script. Please ignore the specific commands mentioned and give a generic solution or clues.

Comment: [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) can control the mininet shell, but it won't be able to control the xterms.

Comment: `xdotool` can send keystrokes to an xterm.

Comment: Check `mn --help`